# Word to describe a very negative, pleasure-killing person

Tags: word-request

I would try to find some more words or expressions to describe a person who is always being negative and brings down the mood of other people.

As far as I can tell, there are "a sourpuss" and "a Debbie Downer". Can I use other words or expressions?

Comment: Oh! I really misunderstood you. You can use *killjoy*. killjoy: a person who deliberately spoils the enjoyment of others.

Comment: spoilsport, wet blanket, party-pooper, stick-in-the-mud...

Comment: The edits to the question title are interesting to me.  "Other than", "outside of", and "beside" all seem fine to me.  What isn't fine is the word "else".

Comment: @snailboat, I noticed the dangling "else" after I saved my first edit, and I wasn't sure to re-edit it since it was still waiting for a peer review. But is *What words can I use outside of X and Y* really okay?

Comment: @DamkerngT. You could ask that as a separate question.  As I said, it seems fine to me!  Someone else might give you a different answer.

Comment: @snailboat, now I wonder why didn't I think of that myself. LOL. Really appreciate.

Comment: Where in the world is *"Debbie Downer"* used?

Comment: Can I also use the word "buzzkill"?

Comment: @Tristan It's an Americanism.  It's used in both the US and Canada.

Comment: snailboat, thanks. I had not heard of that. This site is an education, not just for people learning English.

Comment: In Australia, we also use *wowser*, which refers to the class of ppl that think that having fun is - by definition - frivolous and a waste of time.

Comment: @snailboat, it's more localized than just American. It's not in wide use in northern California, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Killjoy" is a word which can describe a person who is very negative and who attempts to make others feel less comfortable in their surroundings.

"Buzzkill" is a similar term but is a more informal term, whereas "killjoy" is a word found in the dictionary.

Reference:

[Killjoy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/killjoy?q=killjoy)

[Buzzkill](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/buzzkill?q=buzzkill)

Comment: Ngram shows [**"Emotional Vampire"** is more common that "buzzkill"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=buzzkill%2Cemotional+vampire&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbuzzkill%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cemotional%20vampire%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @CoolHandLouis Interesting - I have never heard "Emotional Vampire" before.  Apparently it has been around for a while, but _buzzkill_ appears to have become more popular in recent years.:  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=buzzkill%2Cemotional+vampire&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cbuzzkill%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbuzzkill%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBuzzkill%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cemotional%20vampire%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Adam, I've heard the term "emotional vampire" bunches of times in recent years (like maybe 10 to 20).  I haven't heard Killjoy or Buzzkill at all that I can remember.  But that's just a sample-size n=1 (me).